# Control order of files in subdirectories for rails assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline

I'm using rails to drive a mostly single page app.  I'm also using angular.  So in my assets/javascripts i have directories for controllers, directives, filters, routes, services, etc.  Some of these things, particularly the routes files, need to be semi-ordered.  Is there a clean way to do this? Basically I want to say, do these 3 files in controllers first, then do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can require the files in a specific order in your manifest. Once you've specified all the order dependent files, `require_tree .` will include the rest:

```
//= require controllers/foo.js
//= require controllers/bar.js
//= require_tree .
```